# Copying Panels from one Form to another in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls, panel

I'm replicating a panel with subpanels 
As shown in the following pic:

[image: 5 Panels inside of One Panel]

I use the following code to construct a new Form and try to fill the panel in that form.

```
public Form3(Panel p)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach(Panel child in p.Controls){
        panel1.Controls.Add(child);
    }
}
```

but what ends up happening is as the child gets added, the original Panel starts getting deleted and loses controls.

In the end it skips every other control like in the following picture.
The left side is the original Panel and the right side is the panel in the new form.

[image]

How should I go about doing this? I want the original and the new panel to have the exact same controls. In fact, I don't even know why it's deleting it from the original Panel.

P.S
Inside the constructor I've made sure to see if the original panel that's being passed in has the correct values and they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a control to a parent it will automatically remove it from its previous parent. Then only it will add to new parent.

`Control` provides a property `Parent`. If you add a control in two panels the what yould you expect the `control.Parent` to return? First parent or second?

You need something like this

```
foreach(Panel child in p.Controls)
{
    panel1.Controls.Add(new Panel{ BackColor = child.BackColor });
}
```

Comment: Yea I was thinking I would have to create a new Panel. What would I do for each control INSIDE the subpanel? Because in my real subpanels there are labels and images. Does that mean I have to recreate them?

Comment: Those controls are static or change in runtime?

Comment: The panels will have the same thing inside of them just in different order

Comment: If they can change in runtime then no way you'll have to recreate it. If they are static then just inherit panel add all your controls there and create a instance of it(it will have all childs in place)

Comment: One last thing Sriram. How would I add the eventlisners that the child has?

I tried newP.MouseClick += new child.MouseClick; where newP is the new Panel. But that doesn't work

Comment: @KelseyAbreu Not sure with your question. but you need reflection to find who are all subscribed to those events